# Yosys logic loop falsely detected

Tags: yosys

I've been testing yosys for some use cases.
Version: Yosys 0.7+200 (git sha1 155a80d, gcc-6.3 6.3.0 -fPIC -Os)

I wrote a simple block which converts gray code to binary:

```
module gray2bin (gray, bin);

parameter WDT = 3;

input [WDT-1:0] gray;
output [WDT-1:0] bin;

assign bin = {gray[WDT-1], bin[WDT-1:1]^gray[WDT-2:0]};

endmodule
```

This is an acceptable and valid code in verilog, and there is no loop in it.
It passes compilation and synthesis without any warnings in other tools.
But, when I run in yosys the next commands:

```
read_verilog gray2bin.v
scc
```

I get that a logic loop was found:

```
Found an SCC: $xor$gray2bin.v:11$1
Found 1 SCCs in module gray2bin.
Found 1 SCCs.
```

The next code, which is equivalent, pass the check:

```
module gray2bin2 (
    gray,
    bin
);

parameter WDT = 3;

input [WDT-1:0] gray;
output [WDT-1:0] bin;

assign bin[WDT-1] = gray[WDT-1];

genvar i;
generate
    for (i = WDT-2; i>=0; i=i-1) begin : gen_serial_xor
            assign bin[i] = bin[i+1]^gray[i];
    end
endgenerate

endmodule
```

Am I missing a flag or synthesis option of some kind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using word-wide operators this circuit clearly has a loop (generated with `yosys -p 'prep; show' gray2bin.v`):

[image: gray2bin word-wide xor]

You have to synthesize the circuit to a gate-level representation to get a loop-free version (generated with `yosys -p 'synth; splitnets -ports; show' gray2bin.v`, the call to `splitnets` is just there for better visualization):

[image: gray2bin single bit xor]

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!
I'm not sure it helps though - The main interest for me is the FV feature of Yosys. 
The SMT2 backend give an "ERROR: Found logic loop in module" message. Is it even possible to deliver a netlist to the SMT backend?

Comment: I've checked it - running `synth; splitnets -ports` before `write_smt2` works, and the SMT tool doesn't give ERROR message. 
Thanks!

Comment: One issue gets fixed, and another pops up :)  after running `synth; splitnets -ports` the `write_smt2` doesn't give ERROR message.
But, before adding those lines the BMC found a counter example, but now it doesn't (and ends very fast). So I'm guessing I can't use the "synth" before `write_smt2`, right?

Comment: If your design has hierarchy then splitnets can break it. As I've said I've only included it above script to create a nicer schematic. There should be nothing that prevents write_smt2 to work with the output of `synth`. If there is a problem you should create another question for that and be sure to include the code and scripts necessary to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by CliffordVienna indeed gives a solution, but I also want to clarify that that it's not suitable to all purposes.

My analysis was done for the purpose of formal verification. Since I replaced the `prep` to `synth` to solve the falsely identified logic loops, my formal code got optimized. Wires which I've created that were driven only by the `assume property` pragma, were removed - this made many assertions redundant.
It's not correct to reduce any logic for the purpose of behavioral verification.

Therefore, if the purpose is to prepare a verification database, I suggest not to use the `synth` command, but to use a subset of commands the synth command executes. 
You can find those commands under:
http://www.clifford.at/yosys/cmd_synth.html

In general, I've used all the commands specified in the above link that do not optimize logic:

```
hierarchy -check
proc
check
wreduce
alumacc
fsm
memory -nomap
memory_map
techmap
abc -fast
hierarchy -check
stat
check
```

And everything works as expected.